# Issue of download picture from internet using java code

Tags: java, download

The following code is not working:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class DownloadFile extends Thread {

    URL url;
    long startPos;
    long endPos;
    int length;
    public static ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public DownloadFile(URL url, long startPos, long endPos, int length) {
        this.url = url;
        this.startPos = startPos;
        this.endPos = endPos;
        this.length = length;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            download(new URL(
                    "http://hiphotos.baidu.com/dazhu1115/pic/item/fb8eccffa223a373d6887dfc.jpg"));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void download(URL url) throws IOException {
        String fileName = url.getFile();
        final long size = 8096;
        if (fileName.equals("")) {
            throw new IOException("download webfile \"" + fileName
                    + "\" failed");
        }
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        long total = con.getContentLength();
        System.out.println("file size is " + total);
        con.disconnect();
        if (total <= size) {
            // con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // con.connect();
            // in = con.getInputStream();
            // return download(fileName, in);
            // con.disconnect();
        } else {
            long part = total % size != 0 ? total / size + 1 : total / size;
            long len;
            byte[] b = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < part; i++) {
                len = i != part - 1 ? size : total % size;
                DownloadFile dl = new DownloadFile(url, size * i, size
                        * (i + 1), (int) len);
                pool.execute(dl);
            }
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] b = new byte[length];
        HttpURLConnection con;
        try {
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
            con.setReadTimeout(30000);
            con.setRequestProperty("RANGE", "bytes=" + startPos + "-" + endPos);
            // con.setRequestProperty("GET", fileName + " HTTP/1.1");
            // con.setRequestProperty("Accept","image/gif,image/x-xbitmap,application/msword");
            // con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            con.connect();
            /*
             * in = con.getInputStream(); DataInputStream dis = new
             * DataInputStream(in);
             */
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
                    con.getInputStream());
            int wlen = bis.read(b, 0, length);
            RandomAccessFile oSavedFile = new RandomAccessFile("D:/bbb.jpg",
                    "rw");
            oSavedFile.seek(startPos);
            oSavedFile.write(b, 0, wlen);
            // con.disconnect();
            bis.close();
            oSavedFile.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The size of downloaded picture is correct,but can't view the image of this picture properly. I don't know where the trick is. The following is the image I downloaded
[image]

**Issue resolved, changed my code to** :

```
package com.tom.labs;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class DownloadFile extends Thread {

    URL url;
    long startPos;
    long endPos;
    final static int bufferSize = 1024 * 3;
    public static ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public DownloadFile(URL url, long startPos, long endPos) {
        this.url = url;
        this.startPos = startPos;
        this.endPos = endPos;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            download(new URL("http://hiphotos.baidu.com/dazhu1115/pic/item/fb8eccffa223a373d6887dfc.jpg"));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void download(URL url) throws IOException {
        String fileName = url.getFile();
        final long size = 8096;
        if (fileName.equals("")) {
            throw new IOException("download webfile \"" + fileName + "\" failed");
        }
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        long total = con.getContentLength();
        System.out.println("file size is " + total);
        con.disconnect();
        if (total <= size) {

        } else {
            long part = total % size != 0 ? total / size + 1 : total / size;
            long len;
            byte[] b = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < part; i++) {
                len = i != part - 1 ? size : total % size;
                long startPos = size * i;
                long endPos = startPos + len - 1;
                con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                con.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
                con.setReadTimeout(30000);
                con.setRequestProperty("RANGE", "bytes=" + startPos + "-" + endPos);
                System.out.println("Request Data from " + startPos + " to " + endPos);
                con.connect();

                DownloadFile task = new DownloadFile(url,startPos,endPos);
                pool.execute(task);
            }
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] b = new byte[bufferSize];
        HttpURLConnection con;
        try {
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
            con.setReadTimeout(30000);
            con.setRequestProperty("RANGE", "bytes=" + startPos + "-" + endPos);
            con.connect();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
            RandomAccessFile oSavedFile = new RandomAccessFile("D:/bbb.jpg", "rw");
            oSavedFile.seek(startPos);
            System.out.println("Request Data from " + startPos + " to " + endPos);
            while (startPos < endPos) {
                int wlen = bis.read(b, 0, bufferSize);
                oSavedFile.write(b, 0, wlen);
                startPos += wlen;
            }
            bis.close();
            oSavedFile.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why in the name of Zeus are you using a RandomAccessFile?

Comment: That is a large (in bytes) image for the crappy effect.  Note that there are 'odd aspects' of the image, including that FF shows the size as `Unknown (not cached)` and that while it is declared as JPEG, it is ***animated,*** - suggesting a GIF.  Try it with other more standard images, e.g. any of the ones at my [media page](http://pscode.org/media/#image).

Comment: @Hov I think the OP made a comment to you.

Comment: @Thompson You are right, so I changed my image address,and download it again, now I can see the picture,but not as same as the original one. please see my updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BufferedIntpuStream.read` method returns if there are no more bytes available
so you have to loop until you have written the whole block size.

Here is a Fix for your Problem:

```
       BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
                con.getInputStream());


        RandomAccessFile oSavedFile = new RandomAccessFile("D:/bbb.jpg",
                "rw");            
        oSavedFile.seek(startPos);
        int wlen = 0;
        while (wlen < length) {
            int read = bis.read(b, 0, length);
            wlen += read;
            oSavedFile.write(b, 0, read);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done something like this to extract files:

```
     String imgPath = "/* path to the URL on the internet */ "; 
     String imgFilePath = " /* path to file on disk */ ";

     URL imgUrl;
     try {
        imgUrl = new URL(imgPath);
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(imgUrl.openStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imgFilePath);
        setState(EXTRACTING + imgFilePath);
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);

     } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added some logging statements locally in your code. Below is the log.

```
file size is 69635
Requesting data from position 0 to 8096
Requesting data from position 8096 to 16192
Requesting data from position 32384 to 40480
Requesting data from position 24288 to 32384
Requesting data from position 16192 to 24288
Requesting data from position 48576 to 56672
Requesting data from position 40480 to 48576
Requesting data from position 64768 to 72864
Requesting data from position 56672 to 64768
Writing data starting at 0
Writing data starting at 16192
Writing data starting at 24288
Writing data starting at 48576
Writing data starting at 40480
Writing data starting at 64768
Writing data starting at 56672
Writing data starting at 32384
Writing data starting at 8096
```

See the issue is with multithreading. The program is writing data in the wrong order to a file ending up as a corrupted file. Hope this is clear enough. **Is this a homework?**

Comment: The Problem is that you probably don't read the whole byte array. If Print you would print the number of bytes read from the Stream `System.out.println(String.format("Data written: start %d, length %d", startPos, wlen)); you would see that is something like 'Data written: start 32384, length 96
Data written: start 40480, length 192'

Comment: @Abhilash Hi, I found the issue,it's nothing to do with "order", see my updated post.

Comment: @Tom , I was in the wrong assumption that seek() will point to the end of file ignoring the extra sizes if the argument is larger than the file size. Thats why I thought about writing order. My thought was assuming the length of characters written by each thread is 10 ,if thread 1 writes first 10 characters, then thread 3 writes seeking 20 , but as 20 is above the file length , it will seek upto 10 and start writing from position 11.